# Why shuffle bytes vpshufb in avx512 needs to compute index index[5:0] := b[i+3:i] + (j & 0x30), I don't understand the function of j & 0x30

Tags: intel, intrinsics, avx512

Why does the `vpshufb` byte shuffle in avx512 need to compute index as `index[5:0] := b[i+3:i] + (j & 0x30)`?

The [intrinsics guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512,Other&text=vpshufb&ig_expand=6392) pseudocode for `_mm512_shuffle_epi8(a,b)` (no masking) is:

```
FOR j := 0 to 63
    i := j*8
    IF b[i+7] == 1
        dst[i+7:i] := 0
    ELSE
        index[5:0] := b[i+3:i] + (j & 0x30)
        dst[i+7:i] := a[index*8+7:index*8]
    FI
ENDFOR
dst[MAX:512] := 0
```

I don't understand the function of `j & 0x30` and what's the meaning of it.

Because vpshufb in avx2 doesn't have `(j & 0x30)`, it computes index by `index[3:0] := b[i+3:i]` and `index[3:0] := b[128+i+3:128+i]`.  Docs for `_mm256_shuffle_epi8(a,b)`:

```
FOR j := 0 to 15
    i := j*8
    IF b[i+7] == 1
        dst[i+7:i] := 0
    ELSE
        index[3:0] := b[i+3:i]
        dst[i+7:i] := a[index*8+7:index*8]
    FI
    IF b[128+i+7] == 1
        dst[128+i+7:128+i] := 0
    ELSE
        index[3:0] := b[128+i+3:128+i]
        dst[128+i+7:128+i] := a[128+index*8+7:128+index*8]
    FI
ENDFOR
dst[MAX:256] := 0
```

Comment: It's a 16-byte shuffle within lanes, not like `vpermb`.  Are you looking at the intrinsics guide?  The asm manual's pseudocode https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pshufb never assigns anything to `index[5:0]`, only to an `index` temporary.  Also, are you sure you're even looking at `vpshufb` at all, not `vpermb`?  Only `vpermb` should be using 6 index bits.  `vpshufb` only uses 4-bit indices (and the high bit as a mask) even for 256 and 512-bit vectors.

Comment: thanks, in avx-512 vpshufb(_mm512_shuffle_epi8)  has an 6-bit index. and index[5:0] := b[i+3:i] + (j & 0x30). I'm looking at this intrinsics guide https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#

Comment: It's 4 separate 16-element shuffles using 4-bit indices.  It's just adding `j&0x30` to make a 6-bit index into the right 128-bit lane of the whole vector.

Answer (score 1):

It's 4 separate 16-element shuffles using 4-bit indices, not like `vpermb`. It's adding `j&0x30` to make a 6-bit index into the right 128-bit lane of the source vector, since `j` loops over all 64 destination bytes.  `j & 0xf0` clears the low nibble, the offset-within-lane bits, giving you the byte offset of the start of the lane.  Since `j` only actually goes up to 64, they chose to do `j & 0x30`.

The 256-bit pseudocode unrolls the loop, doing the low byte of the low then high lane, etc.

Intel's asm manual (https://felixcloutier.com/x86/pshufb) is similar, also using a `0x10` or `0x30` mask for a `j` that loops over output bytes. It's weird that the intrinsics guide uses that bit-slicing notation when they don't have to; the index is just an internal temporary, and not part of a larger value; the asm manual just uses `index := src.byte[ j ];`.

```
(KL, VL) = (16, 128), (32, 256), (64, 512)
jmask := (KL-1) & ~0xF
                // 0x00, 0x10, 0x30 depending on the VL
FOR j = 0 TO KL-1
                // dest
    IF kl[ i ] or no_masking
        index := src.byte[ j ];
        IF index & 0x80
            Dest.byte[ j ] := 0;
        ELSE
            index := (index & 0xF) + (j & jmask);
                // 16-element in-lane lookup
            Dest.byte[ j ] := src.byte[ index ];
    ELSE if zeroing
        Dest.byte[ j ] := 0;
DEST[MAXVL-1:VL] := 0;
```

That's weird, it seems like both inputs are called `src`!  `vpshufb dst, src1, src2` uses the 2nd input vector as the index, the first as the table.  Wouldn't be the first or last time there's a mistake in Intel's manual :/

Anyway, the advantage of the asm manual is that the Description section explains what it does in plain English, which helps a lot in thinking through the pseudocode.